# Using domain Active Directory account for connecting to SQL Server running on an Azure VM

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-sql

According to the first note on this [Microsoft Azure article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure): `Connecting to SQL Server running on an Azure VM is not supported using an Azure Active Directory account. Use a domain Active Directory account instead.`

Now, I'm using the free Azure trial account for Azure databases and would like to test the scenario of connecting to a Azure SQL Server database on an Azure VM. Which `domain Active Directory account` should I be using for this test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test in my lab, I could login on SQL server with Azure AD authentication. The user name is `ADSQLAdmin@<your AD>.onmicrosoft.com`, like below:

[image]

Comment: After I opened the LabVM, I changed the password for ADSQLAdmin. Then I went to LabVM (that was already opened) and filled in the info (similar to the ones your screenshot is showing) into the SSMS 2016. But when I entered the new password, it says `Cannot open server "...hotmail.onmicrosoft.com" requested by the login.  The login failed.` I think it probably has something to the fact that I changed the password. Any ideas?

Comment: Your user is `<name>@hotmail.onmicrosoft.com`?

Comment: Hi, we could chat in this room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69147/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-nam

Comment: It's working now. Thank you again for coming to my rescue and pointing out that I was using wrong Authentication. I was using SQL Server Authentication instead of what you show in your screen shot above.

Comment: Now I'm unable to connect to the SQL Server using ADSQLUser account. Any suggestions? I've posted the details [here](https://serverfault.com/q/884938/425441).

Comment: OK, I am checking it.

Comment: We could chat here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69147/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-nam