# Unable to connect as a database contained user to an Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, entra-id, entra-domain-services, azure-sql

On my free trial Azure account, I'm working on Exercise 5 of this [official Azure lab](https://prod-edxapp.edx-cdn.org/assets/courseware/v1/9078c800f062a1dc1271c8ad3e0a0d43/asset-v1:Microsoft+AZURE207x+4T2017+type@asset+block/Databases_in_Azure_Practical_Exercises.pdf) tutorial to work on the section `Connect as a database contained user to an Azure SQL database`. I've successfully created the ADSQLUser as described in the previous sections of the Exercise 5. But when I try connecting to the SSMS in VM (Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server 2016) using the info shown in the image below, I get the following error:

**Error**:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

**SSMS login dialog**:

[image]

**Note**: The same above dialog connects to the SQL Server fine if I use `ADSQLAdmin.....` instead of `ADSQLUser.....` in the `User Name` dropdown above. But according to the tutorial it should connect for `ADSQLUser.....` as well. So what I may be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect SQL, click `Option`,  in the Connect to database text box, type `<your database name>`. They must be same, otherwise you will get this error.

[image]

Comment: That was it. Instead of typing the db name I was looking into the db dropdown and the dropdown did not have that db. After your suggestion of typing the db name, I typed it and it works now (Thank you).